# How to diagnose short freezes/apnea on my Mac

Tags: macos, mac, freeze

I'm using a late-2011 MacBookPro running OSX 10.9.5.

For the last couple of days, I'm experiencing short periods (1-2 seconds) of unresponsiveness where everything freezes, including display, mouse & keyboard. These freezes usually happen in bursts, go away and come back later... Not sure if it's related, but sometimes the screen flickers like it's getting back from a full-screen app (very short fade back from black).

I've tried to understand if it could be software-related. It happens even if there is no app running, and the activity monitor doesn't show anything special (I was expecting to see CPU spikes when freezes happen but no, the activity monitor just freezes like the rest and resumes).

So far, my Googling has found that this is a usual symptom of a failing hard-disk (which could be probable, it's nearly 3 years old and had a bad drop on the floor once). But the Disk Utility's verify doesn't report any issue. And I had a look at the system.log where no disk error could be found.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
A more detailed look at the system.log shows a constant looping (every 10 seconds or less) through the following:

```
Oct  7 13:13:32 Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[186]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4280142
Oct  7 13:13:32 Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[186]: Found 1 modes for display 0x04280142 [1, 0]
Oct  7 13:13:40 Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[186]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4280142
Oct  7 13:13:40 Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[186]: Found 16 modes for display 0x04280142 [16, 0]
Oct  7 13:13:40 Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[186]: CGXMuxAcknowledge: Posting glitchless acknowledge
Oct  7 13:13:40 Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[186]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4280142
Oct  7 13:13:40 Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[186]: Found 1 modes for display 0x04280142 [1, 0]
Oct  7 13:13:40 Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[186]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003f
Oct  7 13:13:40 Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[186]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003f [1, 0]
Oct  7 13:13:40 Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[186]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f0040
Oct  7 13:13:40 Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[186]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f0040 [1, 0]
Oct  7 13:13:48 Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[186]: Received display connect changed for display 0x4280142
Oct  7 13:13:48 Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[186]: Found 45 modes for display 0x04280142 [45, 0]
Oct  7 13:13:48 Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[186]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f003f
Oct  7 13:13:48 Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[186]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f003f [1, 0]
Oct  7 13:13:48 Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[186]: Received display connect changed for display 0x3f0040
Oct  7 13:13:48 Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[186]: Found 1 modes for display 0x003f0040 [1, 0]
Oct  7 13:13:48 Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[186]: MPAccessSurfaceForDisplayDevice: Set up page flip mode on display 0x04280142 device: 0x7f989a6024e0  isBackBuffered: 1 numComp: 3 numDisp: 3
Oct  7 13:13:48 Thomass-MacBook-Pro.local WindowServer[186]: CGXMuxAcknowledge: Posting glitchless acknowledge
```

Would that issue come from the WindowServer process? It happens even after a restart...

Comment: Same here: restarts didn't fix it, even caused stutters in the BIOS screen (?!?!) Unplugging the monitor for a few seconds while running then plugging it back in set it straight. 10.9.5, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 660, graybox (aka Hackintosh)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puzzled about these 'display connect changed' log entries, I plugged an external monitor. This is something I do a lot, but hadn't done since the issue started. I must mention that my external monitor adapter is a little bit wiggly and sometimes I have to plug/unplug it a couple of times before the external monitor gets a signal. Don't know if it comes from the adapter or the Mac's socket.

From the time I plugged it in, the issue disappeared and the repeating log entries stopped! I've just unplugged it, and everything remained normal.

So my best guess is that the last time I unplugged the external monitor adapter, something went wrong and the system kept on receiving plug/unplug events (even after reboots!).

I hope this may help somebody else in the future, although I guess this is a very rare thing to happen!

Comment: Two years later, your answer saved me from a night of going completely insane.  Thank you.